# Problem regarding Netbeans 7.0.1

Tags: netbeans

I have installed Netbeans 7.0.1 from Ubuntu Software Centre.But when I try to use it, its not able to create New Project(Process that I followed: New Project-> Java->Java Application->"Project name").
 Also it is not showing me an option of 'Java Web' while creating a new Project.

Comment: There is a Launchpad bug report about this problem: [netbeans ide cannot create a project](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netbeans/+bug/1360100) which has been confirmed as affecting multiple users using Ubuntu 14.04 and Linux Mint 17.

Answer (score 0):

If all you would be using NetBeans for is Java programming then you can install IntelliJ IDEA 13 Community Edition from the Ubuntu Software Center. IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition is a free (it doesn't cost any money) and open source version of IntelliJ IDEA, a premier IDE for Java, Groovy, Scala and Android applications development. I also tried to install NetBeans IDE 7.0.1 and had the same problem as you have. I searched for a solution and found a Launchpad bug report: Bug #1360100, so I gave up and installed IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition instead.

Eclipse has most of the functionality of NetBeans in one form or another. Or you can download the Oracle Java 8 SE bundle of NetBeans IDE from the Oracle website which contains both Java 8 and NetBeans.